# A linked list is stored in which memory area

Tags: c, linked-list

When we create a linked list it is stored in which region of memory **stack or heap**? 
Suppose we are creating a singly-linked list with 10 nodes. Then will all the nodes be stored in stack or heap or we can store it in any one of heap or stack?

Comment: It depends on how you allocate memory. Mostly linked lists done using dynamic memory allocation. So heap.

Comment: Isn't that like asking "if I put my keys somewhere, where did I put them?" - you know where you put them, we don't.

Comment: @harold what u want to say through ur comment that we can store them in stack as well ae heap according to requirement

Comment: Absolutely. You can even mix them, with some nodes on the stack and some on the heap. Just be careful with the lifetime of nodes on the stack, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly data structure are for effective memory utilization. If you create a linked list with stack variables it will provide the expected result but it is not mean that, memory is utilized properly. Assume heap has may(1000) small blocks of size 10byes & and there is no contentious memory more than 20bytes.  In this case user wants to allocate memory for 100bytes, but there is no contentious memory for 100bytes. In this case user can select linked list data structure to allocate 10bytes memory for 10times. Linked list provides the mechanism to manage the multiple small blocks (called node).

Answer (score 0):

Linked list are created using dynamic memory allocation, say malloc.
Dynamic memory allocations are made from the heap. The heap is a global resource containing all of the free memory in the system. The heap is handled as a linked list of unused blocks of memory, the so called free-list.

Comment: Storage of data depends on how it is allocated. Linked list itself does not require itself to be stored in heap.